# How to plot different data columns using seaborn.FacetGrid?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am following a course in which the instructor used the following code to get 3 subplots (one common column -Price-, and 3 independent variables - Year, EngineV, Mileage -)

```
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True, figsize =(15,3)) #sharey -> share 'Price' as y
ax1.scatter(data_cleaned['Year'],data_cleaned['Price'])
ax1.set_title('Price and Year')
ax2.scatter(data_cleaned['EngineV'],data_cleaned['Price'])
ax2.set_title('Price and EngineV')
ax3.scatter(data_cleaned['Mileage'],data_cleaned['Price'])
ax3.set_title('Price and Mileage')
```

[image: output of the instructor's code]

I am practicing with seaborn and wonder whether there is a way to plot similar output using FacetGrid or similar functions.
I think FacetGrid can only plot within the same variable (like sex which has male and female so can be divided into 2 plots) but mine are 3 independent variables.
Any idea how to plot such a thing?

Comment: Many approaches are possible, depending on personal taste. You can perfectly use `plt.subplots()` together with `sns.set(...)` and `sns.set_style(...)` to obtain a consistent seaborn look.  You can also call `sns.scatterplot(x=data_cleaned['Year'], y=..., ax=a1)`. `FacetGrid`'s main goal is to provide consistent color ranges for data that appears on multiple subplots, which doesn't seem to be the case here.  If you really want to use `FacetGrid`, you can convert the dataframe to ['long form`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data).

Comment: I think you want a [`PairGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html) here, not a `FacetGrid`.